# SMB share client side connection (Win7 with net use) is very slow

Tags: openvpn, server-message-block, net-use

I have a SMB share on a CentOS server. Windows 7 based clients connect to the server via OpenVPN. Then `net use` is used to init the share.

On some clients (not all) I am experiencing very long connection times (from 15 to 40 seconds, with rare terrible peaks of 2 minutes). Once the client is connected, download times of shared files are OK.

I examined network traffic with Wireshark and noticed that those delays are caused by a lot of time that passes between my `net use` command and actual "Negotiate Protocol Request" packet departure from my ip. After that, the connection is estabilished fast. To me, it looks like `net use` just sleeps for a random amount of time before acting, with no known reason.

This happens on various PCs, even with freshly installed Win7 OS.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue (possibly with AD complications).

Comment: I'm using the ip address of the server, so DNS shouldn't be involved, right? I do see loads of NetBios packets on the VPN interface but they don't seem to fill the bandwidth